# Preventing event bubbling

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, event-bubbling

```
function clickHide(){
    if (MouseEvent.button === 0) hide();
}
function hide(){
    using.style.display = "none";
    hidden.style.display = "none";
}
```

I have a problem with event bubbling. The thing is that I have this function `hide()`, which should be called only when clicking the red div. The problem is that it also gets called when I click the yellow div, which is placed inside the red div.  Is there a nice way to prevent this from happening? Heard something about `event.stopPropagation()`, but I don't know how I would use it in this case.

[image: The divs]

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Event.stopPropagation()`. Simply just call the `stopPropagation()` method on the event you are listening to.

Also see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) for more info.

Edit: You can try it like this, it will only fire the event when you click on the parent element. The if statement checks if the target of the event is the parent element then calls `hide()` if not then it returns nothing.

```js
const parentElement = document.querySelector(".parentElement");
const childElement = document.querySelector(".childElement");
parentElement.addEventListener("click", clickHide);

function clickHide(event) {
  if(event.target !== parentElement){
      return;
  } 
  hide();
  
}
function hide() {
    parentElement.classList.add('hidden');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
    <style>
      .parentElement {
        border: 20px solid red;
      }

      .childElement {
        background: yellow;
        padding: 20px;
      }

      .hidden {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="test.js" async defer></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="parentElement">
      <div class="childElement"></div>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the `event.stopPropagation()` method have to be in a different function? Cause when I place it it in my clickHide() function, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can pass the event as parameter to the function which is attached to your `AddEventListener`. in your case im assuming `clickHide()` is referenced in a event listener which i assume looks like this `addEventListener('click', clickHide)`, you can then simply do `function clickHide(event) { event.stopPropagation()} `

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: so I just tried it with this, but the problem is that the event only stops propagating, when it calls the function. But the function that is executed when clicking the parent element, shouldn't be called at all when I'm click the child element :D